# How to Originate Call from Polycom Intercom via Dialplan

Tags: centos, asterisk

We have polycom phones for use with our Asterisk 1.8 PBX.

Consider this:
On the phone at extension 2536, I dial 3333.  This should originate a call from extension 2500 to play a sound.  In other words, I want to use the phone at 2536 to play sounds over another phone.  Now this I am able to do, but I have to *answer* the phone that receives the call.  I want it to auto-answer via it's speakerphone.  I've already [configured the sip.cfg](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Polycom+auto-answer+config) files in the polycom tftp directory.

Both phones are Polycom 601's.

```
[macro-RingAngelusBell]
include => intercom
exten => s,1, NoOp(Ringing-zee dee bell! ${CHANNEL} dialed: ${MACRO_EXTEN})
;same => n,ChanIsAvail(SIP/2500,js)
same => n,Originate(SIP/2500,exten,soundeffects,thebell,1)
same => n,NoOp(Originate Status: ${ORIGINATE_STATUS})
same => n,Hangup()

[soundeffects]
exten => thebell,1(thebell),SIPAddHeader(Alert-Info: Auto Answer)
same => n, Answer()
same => n,NoOp(soundeffects: thebell)
same => n,Playback(soundfx/angelusbell)
same => n,Hangup()
```

I've tried this, too:
In this case, when I dial 3333 from 2536, 2500 rings, but it isn't supposed to.  Instead, 2500 is supposed to CALL "thebell" from it's speakerphone and play the bell sound over it's speaker.

```
[macro-RingAngelusBell]
include => intercom
exten => s,1, NoOp(Ringing-zee dee bell! ${CHANNEL} dialed: ${MACRO_EXTEN})
same => n,SIPAddHeader(Alert-Info: Auto Answer)
same => n,Originate(SIP/2500,app,Dial(thebell))
same => n,NoOp(Originate Status: ${ORIGINATE_STATUS})
same => n,Hangup()
```

And in my sip.cfg:

```
<alertInfo voIpProt.SIP.alertInfo.1.value="Auto Answer"
VoIpProt.SIP.alertInfo.1.class="3"
voIpProt.SIP.alertInfo.2.value="intercom" voIpProt.SIP.alertInfo.2.class="4"
/>
```

`alertInfo.1.value` is set to `"Auto Answer"` because the phone should not ring at all, although I've tried `Ring Answer` and it doesn't make any difference.

I have to say that I'm rather confused... I know what I want but not how to get it!
The call gets originated from the soundplay, but not using the intercom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For polycom phones have be

```
Alert-Info: Ring Answer
```

Or have be in config

```
<voIpProt>
      <alertInfo voIpProt.SIP.alertInfo.1.value="Ring Answer"  voIpProt.SIP.alertInfo.1./>
```

You also can change that option via phone's web interface

Comment: Thanks for your attention.  In the dialplan, it doesn't matter if I send `Ring Answer` or `Auto Answer` - it always rings.  I'm working with a Polycom 601 (which, by the way, I can't find the setting for ring type in it's web interface).

Comment: The problem is that 2500 is supposed to *call* using intercom.

Comment: Yes. Ring Answer = intercom on polycom phones.

Comment: Like I said in my comment, it still rings.  Is there something wrong in my dialplan?

Comment: YES. you use OTHER alert info.

Comment: You missed my point. I've tried both alerts, over and over and over.  It only rings.  The intercom never comes on.  I appreciate your help, but this solution does not work for me.

Comment: It is not clear why i can google while you not. Have you tried this one http://support.polycom.com/global/documents/support/technical/products/voice/Using_SPIP_SSIP_Asterisk_TB43565.pdf  ALERT_INFO set to "alert=intercom" AND allow intercome in phone config? if that still not work, you have contact polycom, they have nice support and they have oficial support of asterisk. they can help you for sure.

Comment: Ha ha, there's no way you are a better googler than I am.  I was hoping for help from someone here; if I could find the help I wanted by googling I would not have posted here.  And I never said I didn't have that in my sip.cfg.  I'm updating my question with my sip.cfg; maybe I've got it mixed up?

Comment: Please note, in that doc Alert-info: alert=intercom. Not like you show in your dialplan

Comment: I've noted.  Like I said many times.  I've tried that and the phone still rings. `Alert-Info: alert=intercom` does NOT work.

Comment: Have you updated your firmware to current one? If still not work after update, ask polycom via email what param have be for your firmware. it is firmware-depended.